# How can I avoid mirror effect of image in coverflow

Tags: macos, cocoa, coverflow, ikimagebrowserview

I have downloaded a coverflow sample from the link

http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-tutorial-image-kit-cover-flow-and-quicklook-doing-things-we-shouldnt-are-too-fun-resist.

I need open flow effect but I dont need miror effect of images.Is it possible to do it.Is there any API available in IKImageFlowView class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is no API available for `IKImageFlowView`. It is a private class. That's why the blog post is titled "doing things we shouldn't." If you look at the project in the blog post, you will find a reverse-engineered `IKImageFlowView.h`. That's as much information as is available. You can use `class-dump` as noted in the blog post and see if you can find the `IKImageFlowViewDelegate` protocol if there is one (this class appears to take a delegate). That might allow you to configure it.

Note that Apple may change this class at any time.

You are probably better off using a third-party implementation like [MBCoverFlowView](http://macindie.com/2009/12/mbcoverflowview-an-open-source-cover-flow-implementation-for-macosx/) or [OpenFlow](https://github.com/thefaj/OpenFlow).

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I will look into this,just for curiousity,does MBCoverFlowView provide a solution to solve my problem.

Comment: @ahmadbaig: Both of those are open-source, so you can look at their headers and/or their implementations to find out.